# how to combine desired columns from different matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

In R, I have two matrices, A and B. How do I merge the second column of B to the last column of A?

Comment: @AaronHall Sorry I forgot to mention it's in R programming. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cbind function:

```
C <- cbind(A, B[,2])
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. Thanks.